# Need big help merging work done outside of git repository

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge, repo

I had another developer help me with some html/css/javascript files. He doesn't work in git, so I just gave him a zip file.

So, in return, he handed me a zip file with all the changes and I cannot figure out the best way to merge the changes in my current branch. I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now.

Every time I create a branch from my current branch and overwrite the files there (with over devs work) then try to merge with my current branch it just overwrites the files without actually merging them (I'm expecting to see some merge conflicts).

Comment: There will only be merge conflicts if you both changed the same code.  If you haven't made any changes on the mainline, then there won't be any merge conflicts.  It's just like you making a change and checking it in.

Comment: You could try create a branch from main and apply your collegues files, and commit it. Then rebase your own branch "on top of it". But like @TimRoberts said, if you haven't changed the same files you will not have conflicts

Answer (score 1):

The best way forward would be to identify which commit was the source for your zip file, create a branch off that commit, dump the zip file, create a commit, merge the branch:

```
git checkout -b external-work $commit-hash-of-the-source-commit
unzip the-archive.zip
git add -u
git add any/new/files that-might have/been/added
git commit -m 'Work from external dev'
git checkout your-branch
git merge external-work
```